# magento 2 view model set payment additional data before place order

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, token, authorize

I am adding a token in payment additional data

```
 getData: function () {
            return {
                'method': "pay_cc",
                'additional_data': {
                    'token_code': this.getToken(),
                }
            };
        },
```

setting this 'token_code' with function

```
            getToken:function(){
            return this.paymentToken;
        },
```

before place order I am generating token and setting setting this before calling 'self.plcaseOrder()' function

```
this.paymentToken = response[0];
console.log("TOKEN CODE");
console.log(this.paymentToken);
self.placeOrder();
return true;
```

When I access this in magento payment method authorize function I am getting null.

How Can I set this token_code??

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Magento dev team removed "auto-saving" additional data into payment and you need to set the payment token from `additional_data` to `additional_information`. This [dev guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/get-payment-info.html) describes how to do it.

As an example, Magento [Vault](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Vault/Observer/PaymentTokenAssigner.php) uses the `publish hash` received from the front end to store it in a payment information.

Comment: I am implementing custom payment method,  even though I am not able to pass my additional data?

Comment: You should not use `additional data` on the backend, use `additional information` instead.